# opencart how 5 products in Featured

Tags: php, twig, opencart, opencart-3

I am using opencart 3.0.3.2 . I want to display 6 products in featured but I don't know where to start from. I am ready to edit code since I won't be making any updates

Comment: if you have any hesitation right now. you can ask me ? i am always available for helping people.

Comment: Okay, my need is to add more columns to 'Featured', by default, it displays four columns but my need is to display 6 columns.

Comment: please send me proper screenshot of your featured 6 column display right now. i definitely help you.

Comment: i update my answer. you can see it. and update your website as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most welcome.you can go to admin side select column left design tab. after going to layout. and select Home Layout as you want anything else. if you want. and save layout. check home page as well.
otherwise if you don't understand you can see following screen shot.

**1. Layout setting :**

[image]

**2. Featured setting :**
Extensions > Extensions > Module > Featured

[image]

**3. Code Changes :** 
catalog\view\theme\default\template\extension\module\featured.twig

**find bolow code**

```
<div class="product-layout col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
```

**Replace**

```
<div class="product-layout col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
```

***after complete above all changes you can see change as your website as well. see below screenshot***

[image]

**i think very helpful for you.**

Comment: It is exactly what I was looking for, I accept it as the answer. Can I remove that product description text to make display more appealing and add some more rows?

Comment: yes definitely. if you want remove description and add some row. it's possible

Comment: Could you help: I want to add more rows and change menus on top to display on left side possibly with Font-Awesome Icon before each menu.

Comment: yes definitely. send me your email id.i will help you. otherwise you can contact to by mail :  bhoraniyamujahid@gmail.com